# How to launch three same EC2 instance in 3 different AZ in one Region without using Auto-scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, subnet

How can I create a CloudFormation template that launches three of the same EC2 instances in three different AZs in the same region, without using Auto Scaling?

For example:

- Instance one in eu-west-1a
- Instance two in eu-west-1b
- Instance three in eu-west-1c

Here is my template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : 2010-09-09
Description: "simple web layer"
Parameters:
  ImageId:
    Description: 'web Layer'
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: ami-244333
  Webservercapacity:
    Default: '3'
    Description: number
    Type: Number
    MinValue: '1'
    MaxValue: '4'
  Securitycab:
    Type: String
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    Description: enter vpc ip range    
  Subnets:
    Description: enter subnet
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Default: subnet-384736383838
  Securitygroup:
    Description: enter sc
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>
    Default: sg-237377383773873
  Vpc:
    Description: enter vpc
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::VPC::Id>
Resources:
  MyEC2Instance:
   Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
   Properties:
     ImageId: !Ref ImageId
     InstanceType: t2.large
     VpcId: !Ref Vpc
     SubnetId: !Ref Subnets
     SecurityGroupIds:
       Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
       Properties:
          VpcId: vpc-1a2b3c4d
          GroupDescription: Sample target security group
          SecurityGroupIngress:    
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 80
            ToPort: 80
            CidrIp: !Ref Securitycab
```

Answer (score 0):

The template should launch three separate instances. Within the properties for each instance, specify the subnet by referring to your `Subnets` parameter (of type `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>`).

You can use [`!Select`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html) to choose the subnet:

```
SubnetId: !Select [ 0, Subnets ]
or
SubnetId: !Select [ 1, Subnets ]
or
SubnetId: !Select [ 2, Subnets ]
```

So it would look like:

```
  Instance1:
   Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
   Properties:
     SubnetId: !Select [ 0, Subnets ]
     ...

  Instance2:
   Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
   Properties:
     SubnetId: !Select [ 1, Subnets ]
     ...
```

Also, rather than defining a security group within the instance properties, define a single Security Group, then have each instance refer to it by reference.